# I am having trouble making a script to fade in/out a list of sprites in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a couple of sprites I want to cycle through with a fade in/out effect for my game's credits scene. I have a script that works, but it only works with one sprite. How can I make it so I can have a list of sprites to cycle through?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class possible : MonoBehaviour
{
public SpriteRenderer sprite;

public Color spriteColor = Color.white;
public float fadeInTime = 1.5f;
public float fadeOutTime = 3f;
public float delayToFadeOut = 5f;
public float delayToFadeIn = 5f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("FadeCycle");
}

IEnumerator FadeCycle()
{
    float fade = 0f;
    float startTime;
    while (true)
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
        while (fade < 1f)
        {
            fade = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, (Time.time - startTime) / 
fadeInTime);
            spriteColor.a = fade;
            sprite.color = spriteColor;
            yield return null;
        }
        //Make sure it's set to exactly 1f
        fade = 1f;
        spriteColor.a = fade;
        sprite.color = spriteColor;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayToFadeOut);

        startTime = Time.time;
        while (fade > 0f)
        {
            fade = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, (Time.time - startTime) / 
fadeOutTime);
            spriteColor.a = fade;
            sprite.color = spriteColor;
            yield return null;
        }
        fade = 0f;
        spriteColor.a = fade;
        sprite.color = spriteColor;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayToFadeIn);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: get a list, take that code and replace all the specific sprites with one of a foreach on the list

Comment: I tried but it gives me errors.

Comment: then normal ettiqutte would have been to post the code you tried, asking for help and explaining whats wrong with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets do a simple refactor, and take the bit that does the actual work, and seperate it out into a method. So those two lines:

```
        spriteColor.a = fade;
        sprite.color = spriteColor;
```

Can be turned into a method, and called in youro code instead

```
 void SetFade(float fade)
 {
        spriteColor.a = fade;
        sprite.color = spriteColor;
 }
```

Then the rest of your code gets shorter and is already mor readable:

```
IEnumerator FadeCycle()
{
 float startTime;
 while (true)
  {
     startTime = Time.time;
     while (fade < 1f)
     {
         fade = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, (Time.time - startTime) / fadeInTime);
         SetFade(fade);      
         yield return null;
     }
     SetFade(1);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayToFadeOut);
     startTime = Time.time;
     while (fade > 0f)
     {
         SetFade(Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, (Time.time - startTime) / fadeOutTime));
         yield return null;
     }
     SetFade(0);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayToFadeIn);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if you want to apply the change to multiple sprites you only have to do int in one place. Change your declaration from:

```
public SpriteRenderer sprite;
```

to

```
public SpriteRenderer[] sprites;
```

And finally we can modify our SetFade method to be:

```
void SetFade(float fade)
  {
          spriteColor.a = fade;
          foreach(var sprite in sprites)
            sprite.color = spriteColor;
 }
```

Comment: getting error CS0103: The name 'fade' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Fixed it, but it is rendering them all at once.

Comment: you didn't mention you wanted them not all at once

Comment: My bad, sorry. I will work on that in future comments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but shortly you can add a black sprite/canvas image that covers all scene with alpha = 0 and with a similar method of yours change alpha to 1. It should have better performance than looping each sprite.

If you want separate control on each sprite: add SpriteRenderer parameter to your method and store your all sprites in a list and call your method for each sprite in spriteList. For better practice, you can add an extension method to [SpriteRenderer](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/12/29/fading-sprites-unity-5/)